# Textfields in different Windows update to same Value

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to Cocoa Programming.
So this may be an easy to solve Question.
I am playing around with Cocoa Bindings at the moment. And have a simple set up.

I have two windows with separate .xib files and WindowController Classes.
Each window has a TextField that is bound to the same Class/Object, that contains an NSString.

If I change the value on TextField in the "first" window, nothing happens and the TextField in the "second" window is not updated.
If I put a label in the "first" window, and bind its value all is working fine, and the labels value change when I change the TextField in the same window.

How do I get the TextField in the second window to update itself, when I change the Value in the first windows TextField?
The only way I get this to work is when I bind the TextFields to NSUserDefaultsController. But storing the data is not what I am looking for.

I was searching the web, but could not find a proper solution, so any help is welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: Try giving them the same shared window controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now as answer. 
Use the same shared window controller. 
That will easily enable both windows to be different views of the same data model.